# Внедрить свою базу данных Realm в проект Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

Сталкнулся с проблемой, не могу внедрить свою БД в проект, нужно именно внедрить ее, так как она у меня готовая, на официальном сайте нашел это:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Get the URL to the bundled file
    fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyBundledData", withExtension: "realm"),
    // Open the file in read-only mode as application bundles are not writeable
    readOnly: true)

// Open the Realm with the configuration
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)

// Read some data from the bundled Realm
let results = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age > 5")
```

Добавил БД в папку `Assets`, но она не видит ее, пишет ошибку `A Realm Configuration must specify a path or an in-memory identifier.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взято со англоязычного ресурса.
Решил проблему так:
Создал модель:

```
final class ContentModel: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var content = ""
    @objc dynamic var listName = ""
    @objc dynamic var id = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "id"
    }
}
```

Создал базу:

```
let model = ContentModel()
model.id = 1
model.listName = "List Item 1"
model.title = "Title of content 1"
model.content = "Sample Text"

// Get the default Realm
let realm = try! Realm()

// Persist your data easily
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(model)
}
```

Путь к дефолтной БД:

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```

Далее переходим по пути который выдал нам `print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)`
и копируем себе в проект БД.

Переходим в настройки нашего проекта, далее во вкладку`Copy Bundle Resources`, добавляем наш `default.realm`.

Создаем конфигурацию для `Realm`:

```
open class func getBundledRealm() -> Realm {
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        // Get the URL to the bundled file
            fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "realm"),
        // Open the file in read-only mode as application bundles are not writeable
        readOnly: true)

// Open the Realm with the configuration
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)

    return realm
}
```

Тестируем базу:

```
let realm = RealmUtils.getBundledRealm()

// Read some data from the bundled Realm
let results = realm.objects(ContentModel.self)

for item in results {
    print("Id: \(item.id)")
}
```

[Клик на оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987179/how-to-create-a-pre-prepared-database-and-then-load-that-data-in-my-ios-swift-ap)

Answer (score 1):

Не надо добавлять в Assets, достаточно, чтобы файл базы данных был на одном уровне с вашими контроллерами и AppDelegate.swift в проекте. К тому же справа в инспекторе должна стоять галочка, что этот ресурс нужен для вашего "target". Проверить это можно так - идете в настройки проекта и на вкладке Build Phases надо зайти в раздел Copy Bundle Resources. И там вы должны увидеть свой файл. Это означает, что при сборке, Xcode скопирует этот файл БД в вместе с исполняемым кодом. Вы можете посмотреть Examples, которые идут вместе с Realms - там есть пара включенных БД для target - Migration.

Comment: Я сделал так как указали, ошибка не исчезла! Ругается на эту `let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)` строку.